# R function Mclust slow

Tags: r, opencv, fortran, cluster-analysis

I used the Mclust function in the mclust package for EM-Clustering of a vector of about 27,000 entries into two clusters:

```
Mclust(data_vector, G=2)
```

Another software that uses opencv for the EM-Clustering is about 3 times faster than Mclust (even if I reduce the maximum number of iterations in Mclust to e.g. 4). In the mclust source it looks like the function is implemented in fortran.

How can it be that it seems to be slower than the opencv implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Try running both with the exact same:

- initial conditions
- model (with/without covariance etc.)

I believe `Mclust` does a quite expensive initialization. If openCV starts with a random sample as initialization, no wonder it is faster.

So for a starter, give both the exact same vector to start with.